# Isolate and display red channel from webcam stream openCV

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, webcam

Using below code to isolate the red channel and have it appear red in the stream displayed.

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)   
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    red = frame[:, :, 2]
    new = np.zeros(frame.shape)
    new[:, :, 2] = red
    #flip = cv2.flip(dummy, 1)
    cv2.imshow( 'frame', new )

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

what i see is a uniform bright red stream but frame[:, :, 2] gives me the correctly isolated channel but in grayscale.

Comment: Don’t know if this is the issue, but you may want to make sure that `new` has the same `dtype` as `frame`: `new = np.zeros_like(frame)`.

Comment: Worked like a charm np.zeros_like is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

When you do `red = frame[:, :, 2]`, this extracts the red channel and is just a 2D array with values ranging from 0 to 255. If you print the shape, you will see that it has only one dimension. If you display this image, the output looks like a grayscale image but these are actually red channel values. To visualize only the red channel, you need to set the blue and green channels to zero.

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)   
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Set blue and green channels to 0
    frame[:, :, 0] = 0
    frame[:, :, 1] = 0
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```